# Google Chrome Bookmarks sync keeps overwriting my bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

So I've recently spent an afternoon re-organizing all my booksmarks, and then I accidentally deleted at important folder (which contained a lot of bookmarks).

I managed to restore it, by copying the `bookmarks` and `bookmarks.bak` files, and I also kept copy of the newly-organised bookmarks `bookmarks` and `bookmarks.bak` file so I could restore them later...

After importing my original booksmarks to firefox (essentially giving me a 'copy' of the deleted folder), I tried to replace the two bookmarks files with the newly organized ones.

However, everytime I do this, chrome re-synchs and replaces the bookmark file with the original. I have tried disabling the synch feature, and this solves the issue temporarily, but as soon as I turn the synch back on, it once again restores it.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out!

Turns out (as expected) chrome stores all bookmark data on a server, then every time you sign in a device it will download the bookmarks to the device.

The way to get round it is resetting the server synch data, which can be found [here](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync). Then once it's reset, close chrome, restore the `bookmark` and `bookmarks.bak` files, reload chrome, sign in and done!

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that if you have icloud bookmarks extension in chrome this also mixes up bookmarks.
Uninstalling this extension cures the problem immediately

Comment: Any details on how bookmarks get mixed up?